# Hidden state of the Bottom Sheet

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I am trying to set hidden state for `BottomSheet`, but it doesn't work. What's the problem?

```
 bottomBar = BottomSheetBehavior.from(findViewById(R.id.bottom_bar));
 bottomBar.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: At what point in your activity's lifecycle are you doing this?

Comment: onCreate() method

Comment: To hide the bottom sheet, the user can swipe it down to hide it from the screen or you can set the BottomSheetBehavior to STATE_COLLAPSED

Comment: STATE_COLLAPSED doesn't work. I wanna to hide BottomSheet like ActionBar when called hide() method.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Remember to add this while hiding the bottom sheet at start of activity/fragment

```
bottomSheetBehavior =BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottom_sheet_view_here);
bottomSheetBehavior.setHideable(true);//Important to add
bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: setHideable(true) was what I was looking for

Comment: Wow... That should be true by default.

Answer (score 12):

```
mBottomSheetBehaviour.setPeekHeight(0);
```

use this and it will hide.

Answer (score 5):

try the following :

```
LinearLayout bottomSheetViewgroup  
= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);

BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior =  
BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheetViewgroup);
```

then use

```
bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you're not doing this too early in your Activity's lifecycle. If you need to do it in `onCreate` or something similar, try putting it in a `Runnable` that you post to a view, like so:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        bottomBar = BottomSheetBehavior.from(findViewById(R.id.bottom_bar));
        bottomBar.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
    }
 });
```

It's not the cleanest solution, but it's sometimes unavoidable.

Comment: This is the only approach that worked for me of all the solutions.

Answer (score 1):

```
 bottomsheetbehavior.setPeekHeight(0, true);
```

to hide with a small  animation :)

or

```
            bottomSheet.animate()
                    .translationYBy(bottomSheetBehavior.getPeekHeight());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `BottomSheetBehaviour.STATE_COLLAPSED`

```
bottomBar = BottomSheetBehavior.from(findViewById(R.id.bottom_bar));
bottomBar.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use something like a Tabbed Activity, you can hide your bottomsheetlayout in your Fragment.

I thing this possible, because the fragment view is created after the activity view.

```
class "activity"
   public void hideBottomSheet(){ 
      sheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
   }

class "fragment"
   onCreateView()
      ((YourActivity.class)getActivity()).hideBottomSheet();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way -
this way you don't need `Fragments`:

```
boolean init = true;


layoutBottomSheet.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutChange(View view, int i, int i1, int i2, int i3, int i4, int i5, int i6, int i7) {
            if(init)hideBottomSheet();
            init=false;
        }
    });
```